# JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 19 column 41 Python

Tags: python, json, url, excepciones

Tengo un problema con la lectura de fichero desde una url. Estoy usando urllib y todo va bien hasta que hago el json.loads(), al parecer el problema está en que hay caracteres del tipo "\N", querría saber alguna forma de pasara esos caracteres a " " (espacio en blanco) he intentado con replace y otros métodos pero me salen errores distintos...
la lectura del fichero seria algo así:

```
{
  "id": 56811,
  "a_id": 103325,
  "a_image": "http://google.com",
  "c_image": "http://google.com",
  "origin": "The world where people cant breathe",
  "gender": "Female",
  "name": "Randome name",
  "desc": "random name is a character from The world where people cant breathe",
  "quotes": [
    {
"SERIES": "The world where people cant breathe?",
"LINE_ID": 5518,
"SRT_ID": 14,
"EPID": 1,
"PID": 103325,
"QUOTE_URL": "http://google.com",
"SUB_LINE": "Really?
"
    },
    {
"SERIES": "The world where people cant breathe?",
"LINE_ID": 5519,
"SRT_ID": 14,
"EPID": 1,
"PID": 103325,
"QUOTE_URL": "http://google.com",
"SUB_LINE": "Tell me the truth!
"
    },
    {
"SERIES": "The world where people cant breathe?",
"LINE_ID": 5523,
"SRT_ID": 14,
"EPID": 1,
"PID": 103325,
"QUOTE_URL": "http://google.com",
"SUB_LINE": "You're right.
"
    },
    {
"SERIES": "The world where people cant breathe?",
"LINE_ID": 5524,
"SRT_ID": 14,
"EPID": 1,
"PID": 103325,
"QUOTE_URL": "http://google.com",
"SUB_LINE": "You may leave now.
"
    },
    {
"SERIES": "The world where people cant breathe?",
"LINE_ID": 5526,
"SRT_ID": 14,
"EPID": 1,
"PID": 103325,
"QUOTE_URL": "http://google.com",
"SUB_LINE": "I don't know who you are,
"
    },
    {
"SERIES": "The world where people cant breathe?",
"LINE_ID": 5527,
"SRT_ID": 14,
"EPID": 1,
"PID": 103325,
"QUOTE_URL": "http://google.com",
"SUB_LINE": "but pulling off a locked room delivery\Nrather than a locked room murder...
"
    },
```

**El formato del error es \N(Cualquier Palabra)**. No estoy realmente seguro de ello pero teniendo en cuenta que el problema es el Invalid \escape entiendo que es ese. También aclarar que el hecho de que ponga "linea 19 column 41" no es muy acertado ahora mismo ya que voy usando distintos json de el mismo sition entonces los errores van cambiando pero siempre tienen en comun que todos tienen los caracteres "\N".

Una vez cambiado el código gracias a la aportación de *fedorqui 'SO deja de dañar'* este es el código aunque sigo teniendo otros errores:

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'
url = f"example.asdf"
headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,} 
request=urllib.request.Request(url,None,headers) #The assembled request
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
data = str(data)
data = data.replace(r"\N", " ")
text2 = json.loads(data)
```

Una vez hecho eso obtengo el siguiente error...
`JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` 
He intentado usar `data = json.dumps(data)` Pero aún asi me aparecen otros errores

Comment: Bienvenidy Lucky! Puedes poner un ejemplo del json que tienes real por favor, el ejemplo que has puesto nos es un json valido y no tiene el error que comentas.

Comment: De acuerdo, ya está cambiado, Lo único es que debido a la longitud del código no puedo ponerlo entero aun así creo que he abarcado la excepción desde mi punto de vista

Comment: No estoy seguro de si ese es el json que lees realmente... si es así, no es un json válido debido al mal uso de las comillas, por ejemplo en esta línea -> `"desc": "random name is a character from The world where people cant breathe"",` acaba con dos comillas dobles cuando solo debería haber una

Comment: No, eso ha sido una errata de mi parte, al cambiar las urls y tal para subir la pregunta. No quería que se viera la página y tal por algunos temas. El formato del JSON está aparentemente bien aunque el problema viene dado en los carateres "\N"

Comment: es que el problema está en el "\N". Si coges la cadena y la intentas asignar a una variable, ya da este error: _SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 1426-1427: malformed \N character escape_. ¿De dónde viene esto y por qué usa "\N" en lugar de "\n"?

Comment: No se bien la razón de porque tiene ese formato tan raro pero precisamente es eso lo que necesito cambiar, el \N cambiarlo a " " de alguna forma para hacer skip del error

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en el "\N" que aparece en el texto. Simplificando mucho, puede reproducirse con este simple:

```
>>> d = """hola\Nadios"""
File "<ipython-input-11-21db9b8e00d7>", line 1
d = """hola\Nadios"""
^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 4-5: malformed \N character escape
```

Una manera de leer la cadena es marcarla como "raw" (cruda, sin procesar) con el prefijo `r`:

```
>>> d = r"""hola\Nadios"""
```

Luego es solo cuestión de reemplazar los "\N" por un salto de línea o lo que quieras:

```
>>> d.replace(r"\N", "\n")
'hola\nadios'
>>> e = d.replace(r"\N", "\n")
>>> print(e)
hola
adios
```

Comment: data = response.read() # The data u need
data = str(data)
data = data.replace(r"\N", " ")
text2 = json.loads(data)
Una vez hecho eso obtengo el siguiente error... JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
He intentado usar 
data = json.dumps(data)
Pero aún asi me aparecen otros errores

Comment: por favor edita tu publicación con un ejemplo reproducible. En comentarios es muy difícil leer código

Comment: Hecho, perdón soy algo nuevo aquí